# Bottle Conditioning with Saison Yeast - Any adjustments to priming sugar necessary?

Tags: bottle-conditioning, saison, wyeast

I have 6 Saisons brewing, three using Wyeast 3711 French Saison and three using Wyeast 3724 Belgian Saison. The final gravities on these have been my lowest ever for any batch of beer.

The 3711's ended up around 0.998-0.999, while the 3724's ended up between 1.004 - 1.0045. *Both started with an OG of 1.050.

Given that these two strains of yeast do such a good job of converting sugar into alcohol (and CO2), do I need to adjust the amount of priming sugar downwards to avoid an over-carbonated beer?

Edit with the recipe:

I made three 6 gallon batches:

1) 100% pilsener

2) 50% pilsener 50% vienna

3) 50% pilsener 50% munich

These were all mashed at 147-148*F/64.4*C for 90 minutes.

I then split each batch into two carboys, giving me six, 3-gallon batches total. I made a 2L yeast starter for both the 3711 and 3724, and split them into 3 mason jars each (brewer's friend said I hit the correct cell count given I was using 3 gallon instead of 6 gallon batches).

The purpose of the experiement was to see the difference between vienna and munich in a Saison, and also see the difference between 3711 and 3724.

Comment: What was the OG's that turned into 0.998 and 1.004, just to know?

Comment: @jards 1.050. Edited, thanks.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the recipes. The super-high attenuation may indeed be influenced by the strain's particularly high attenuation limit, but is likely much more impacted by using high proportions of simple, highly fermentable sugars, traditional for most Belgian styles.

Comment: @FranklinPCombs I added the recipes and context. I did not add any corn sugar or other adjuncts. This is the first time I used a saison yeast (and measured the FG/OG), but I thought that hitting this low was pretty common for this yeast?

Comment: Great, thanks. I don't know much about this strain's particular attenuation limits, I just think that's pretty incredible attenuation for an all-malt wort. Would you mind sharing your mashing procedure? Seems like you must have done something to encourage large proportions of fermentable sugars.

Comment: @FranklinPCombs Yes, I was shocked when I read the gravity readings after 2 weeks. I don't believe I have ever dropped lower than 1.010 before. These were all mashed at 147-148*F/64.4*C for 90 minutes, in an attempt to maximize fermentable sugars. The mash was single infusion in the sense that there were no steps, although I had to keep adding 1/8 to 1/4 boiling water every 15 minutes to maintain temperatures. The water to grain ratio was originally 1.25 quarts per pound of grain.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, you don't need to change a thing.

Comment: I use 3711 often, Denny is right.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. Keep your priming sugars the same.

Explanation: The sugars we usually use for carbonation is 100% (or near 100%) fermentable. Thus, it will cause the same amount of carbonation.

Answer (score 2):

if people are still wondering about these results.. both of these strains were found to be S. cerevisiae var. diastaticus and contain the gene that allows them to chop up dextrins and do this very slowly. Basically you end up with lower FG's than you would expect based on the target and recipe procedure.

I was myself wondering if people have bottle conditioned with either of these strains? I was worried about the yeast continuing in bottle and ended up over-carbed.
If you have bottle conditioned, how much time passed before bottling? and how long did you wait before opening the last of the bottles? what were your results?

Answer (score 1):

I just finished a saison using 3724. Gravity went from 1.055 to 1.009. I used the amount of priming sugar for 3.2 volumes, and after 1.5 weeks in bottles they are VERY carbonated. I was thinking I might dial mine back next time.

However, I don't think you are in danger of making bottle bombs just from the bottling sugar, so I would say just try them out in a couple weeks and see if an adjustment needs to be made for the next batch and note it in your brew log.

---

Info for the beer mentioned above. I don't have my brew log on me, but original recipe called for:

Single infusion mash, Starting Mash Thickness: 1.25 qt/lb, target 155 degrees at dough-in. Rest for 60 min. I mash in a cooler without heat, so the temperature would have dropped probably into the high 140s after 60 minutes.
Fly sparge.

Fermentation was 10 weeks (2.5 months) at 70 degrees (temp controlled with a heat wrap). The temp is on the low end for this yeast. I intend to do another batch at a higher temp to compare the yeast character. It was also at about double the standard pitch rate. I do 2.5 gal batches but pitch a whole Wyeast smack-pack.

Comment: Hi CodingWithSpike, would you mind editing your answer and including the recipe you used, the mash temperatures/duration, and how long you fermented before bottling? I'm trying to determine the discrepancy between our FGs using this yeast (given that our OG's are roughly the same). I had an episode a month ago where I had about 30 bottle bombs in one night so I'm trying to avoid that again :).

Comment: I disagree @CodingSpike, bottle bombs are very possible from just the bottling sugar. I know this from experience.

Comment: @AtronSeige I would guess that either fermentation wan't complete, or way too much priming sugar then. I've had a brew drop 20 points in the bottle before they started too explode (I didn't give a bret beer long enough to finish). Corn sugar for 3.2 vol CO2 would only add about 4 points of gravity, which shouldn't be nearly enough to cause a bottle to burst if the beer was actually done fermenting.

Comment: @MatthewMoisen Added some mash and fermentation details above.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "it depends".  If you are using corn sugar, dextrose, or any other simple sugar for priming - then no, you don't need to change anything.

If you're using DME for priming or anything that would have "unfermentable" sugars in it, well - the saison yeast is just going to digest those things, meaning typical priming sugar calculators are going to be wrong, and you will get *way* more carbonation than expected.  You would possibly be at risk of bottle bombs.